# how to group in a logs and count each subgroup in bash

Tags: bash, awk, count, grep, grouping

I want to analyse a log file. It has several  operations, each containing a set of sub-operations.
I would like to extract the number of sub-operations grouped by operations.
That's quite easy in sql but I am getting stuck in bash.

Here's a simplified version of the file:

```
    [21:30:21.538Z #a9a.012 DEBUG -            -   ] c.h.c.w.j.JobTrackingWorkerReporter: Reporting bulk completion: Partition: tenant-xla; Job: ingestion-4759-9-13-41; Tasks: [ingestion-4759-9-13-41.1.43, ingestion-4759-9-13-41.1.44, ingestion-4759-9-13-41.1.41]

otherlogs stuff ...

[21:31:21.538Z #a9a.012 DEBUG -            -   ] c.h.c.w.j.JobTrackingWorkerReporter: Reporting bulk completion: Partition: tenant-xla; Job: ingestion-4757-10-17-4; Tasks: [ingestion-4757-10-17-4.1.2, ingestion-4757-10-17-4.1.1, ingestion-4757-10-17-4.1.3, ingestion-4757-10-17-4.1.4]

otherlogs stuff ...

[21:31:21.690Z #a9a.012 DEBUG -            -   ] c.h.c.w.j.JobTrackingWorkerReporter: Reporting bulk completion: Partition: tenant-xla; Job: ingestion-4757-10-18-3; Tasks: [ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.137, ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.139, ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.138, ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.140, ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.136, ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.141]
```

Each operation is the part before the dot, the rest belongs to any suboperation.

I am looking for a result like the following, that I could store in a file for example:

```
operationName            suboperationCount
ingestion-4757-10-18-3         3
ingestion-4757-10-18-4         4
ingestion-4757-10-18-3         6
```

I have been trying few combinations like  `cat xlogs.txt | grep 'ingestion' | uniq | wc -w > fileresult.txt`

But that would only return the global number.

Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***EDIT:*** After OP's comment got to know we need to only include ids inside `TASKS` so in that case you could try following, strictly considering that you have only 1 `TASK` string occurring in your Input_file per line.

```
awk '
{
  sub(/.*Tasks/,"Tasks")
  while(match($0,/ingestion-[0-9-]+/)){
    arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,arr[i]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

With `awk` could you please try follwing, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/ingestion-[0-9-]+/)){
    arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,arr[i]
  }
}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  while(match($0,/ingestion-[0-9-]+/)){     ##Running while loop till match function returns a TRUE result after matching regex init.
    arr[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++        ##Creating array arr whihc has index as matched regex substring and keep increasing its value by 1 here.
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)            ##Now saving rest of the line(after the matched regx above) into current line.
  }
}
END{                                        ##Starting END block of this awk program from here.
  for(i in arr){                            ##Traversing through arr all elements here.
    print i,arr[i]                          ##printing index of array and value of array with index of i.
  }
}' Input_file                               ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `grep + uniq` command:

```
grep -Eo '\bingestion-[0-9-]+' file.log | uniq -c
```

```
  4 ingestion-4759-9-13-41
  5 ingestion-4757-10-17-4
  7 ingestion-4757-10-18-3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, great compiled solution, but it takes the extra "Job: ingestion" so all count results will have to be -1

Comment: Sorry, I actually tested your solution on a larger document and it failed. The reason being that your code actually checks each line then compile. So, if for some reasons (what's happening in my logs), there is job1[task1, task2, task3] coming in. Then job2[task1, task2, task3], then again job1[task3, task4, task5] we will have two different lines for job1, which is not what we expect. A loop as described in the other solution might be the best way to go. My bad, I may have failed to provide a good sample from the start. Thanks anyway for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

```
$grep -o  'ingestion[\.0-9-]*\.'  file | uniq -c
      3 ingestion-4759-9-13-41.1.
      4 ingestion-4757-10-17-4.1.
      6 ingestion-4757-10-18-3.1.
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot, you are adding a dot to each results but I understand that it's to avoid considering the extra occurrence with "Job: ingestion-" which makes the count being right.

Comment: Sorry, I actually tested your solution on a larger document and it failed. The reason being that your code actually checks each line then compile. So, if for some reasons (what's happening in my logs), there is **job1[task1, task2, task3]** coming in. Then  **job2[task1, task2, task3]**, then again  **job1[task3, task4, task5]** we will have two different lines for job1, which is not what we expect. A loop as described in the other solution might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I added awk to your code because it is readable:

```
cat xlogs.txt | grep -o -E 'ingestion[0-9-]+' | uniq -c | awk ' 
     {if (NR == 1){
        print "operationName suboperationCount" > "fileresult.txt";
     }
     print $0=$2 " " $1 >> "fileresult.txt"
     }'
```